# How can I write nested code on a nested list with markdown?

Tags: discussion, markdown, code-block, list

I need to write a nested code block on a sub element of a list.

My list look like

````
1. element 1
1. element 2
1. element 3, this has subelements
    1. sub element 1
    1. sub element 2 this one has a code block
    ```
    #!Shell

    line of code 1
    line of code 2
    line of code 3
    ```
    1. sub element 3
1. element 4
````

but it does not work... How can I make this happen?

thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply need to indent those code lines a bit (8 spaces) more:

---

1. element 1
2. element 2

   ```
   // code here, 8 spaces
   ```
3. element 3, this has subelements

   1. sub element 1
   2. sub element 2 this one has a code block

      ```
      #!Shell, 12 spaces

      line of code 1
      line of code 2
      line of code 3
      ```

      1. And four more for here:

         ```
         # a whole bunch of spaces
         ```
   3. sub element 3
4. element 4

---